# Identity Server 3 Authentication/Authorization, with ASP.NET CORE 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, identityserver3, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm currently working on a RESTful project built upon ASP.NET Core 1.0 which connects to an Identity Server 3. I set a global [Authorize] Filter for all Controllers in the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs.

I now try to validate my Bearer Token from an AJAX Request against my Identity Server 3 in the Startup.cs of the CORE 1.0 project and thus Authorize my controller resources.

It seems so much changed in ASP.NET CORE 1.0 compared to (classic) ASP.NET 4.5.

Do you have some ideas how to achieve this? How to validate my token in ASP.NET Core 1.0?

Many Thanks!

**UPDATE**

In Asp.net 4.5 I was able to use **app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication**(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions(){...}) but this doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Instead I try to use the following :

```
var connectOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {      
                Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerSettings:CoreUrl"],
                ClientId = Configuration["IdentityServerSettings:ClientId"],
                ClientSecret = Configuration["IdentityServerSettings:ClientSecret"],
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["IdentityServerSettings:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code
            };
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(connectOptions);
```

Unfortunately all I get is a HTTP 302...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation to solve this issue :)

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ScopeName = Configuration["IdentityServerSettings:ApiScopes"],
                Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerSettings:CoreUrl"]
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is is you want to use a Bearer Token Authentication middleware.

The package that you're looking for is`"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0"`

Comment: Thanks Lutando, though I'm not so sure if JwtBearer Middleware can solve my issue with Identiy Server 3... hm